# Django REST serialize single model instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize a model instance of type `Shift` but I'm getting an error.

> 'Shift' object has no attribute 'get'

```
shift = models.Shift.objects.get(pk=8)
ser = serializers.ShiftSerializer(many=False, data=shift)
ser.is_valid()
```

ShiftSerializer is a ModelSerializer.
This works if I get the shift using `filter` and `all` and `many=True`.

**Solution:**

```
shift = models.Shift.objects.get(pk=8)
ser = serializers.ShiftSerializer(shift)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `data` parameter is for deserializing, not serializing. You should just pass the model instance as a positional arg.

```
obj = serializers.ShiftSerializer(shift)
```

Note there's no need to specify many=False, that's the default. Also, it doesn't make sense to call `is_valid()` on the serializer you've constructed from a model instance; again, that's for deserialization.